# How to give image path in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use an image that is located in `app/assets/revolution/assets/01.png`.

I'm not using the by default `app/assets/images` folder. I want to use my own folder name `'revolution'` where I'v made my own `assets` folder.

How do I give the image path in my index view? I'm trying to do it like this:

```
<%= image_tag ('revolution/assets/01.png') %>
```

Comment: If you were brave enough to violate rails naming conventions, you should be a hero figuring out all the consequences yourself.

Comment: Soory don't understand what you say

Answer (score 2):

You need to put that revolution folder in assets path first then you will be able access files from it.

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app/assets", 'revolution')
```

Than only you will be able to access file from assets path like below.

```
<%= image_tag('01.png') %>
```

If you do not want to put your folder in assets images path. We have 2 ways of doing same. Either move your folder to assets/images or to public path (rails ways) in both way you can easily access file.

Comment: Add `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app/assets", 'images/revolution')` in application.rb & then `<%= image_tag('01.png') %>`

Comment: @Salil His revolution folder is not in images.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the helper asset_url

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url

But you would strongly advise you to use the default folder if you want to do that.

@mudasobwa While it's true, you don't have to be such a d..k in your reply :/. It's not as if we never coded shit when discovering new languages / libs / concepts

@Gagan Gami
You could, but you would then avoid the asset pipeline and are going to have a huge cache problem with your browser the day you replace your file while keeping the name.